# Difference between rceps and cceps in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cepstral-analysis

I'm trying to construct a cepstrum using MATLAB built in function but I don't get the difference between MATLAB's functions rceps and cceps.
Can anyone explain to me the difference between rceps and cceps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- rceps: The real cepstrum is the inverse Fourier transform of the real logarithm of the magnitude of the Fourier transform of a sequence.
- cceps: Cepstral analysis is a nonlinear signal processing technique that is applied most commonly in speech processing and homomorphic filtering. It returns the complex cepstrum of the real data sequence using the Fourier transform. 
  [Matlb signal processing tool box]

Answer (score 2):

RTFM? [`rceps`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/rceps.html) says:

```
y = real(ifft(log(abs(fft(x)))));
```

while [`cecps`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cceps.html) says:

```
h = fft(x);
logh = log(abs(h)) + sqrt(-1)*rcunwrap(angle(h));
y = real(ifft(logh));
```